# C - Reading from a .txt file and storing the characters inside an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, while-loop, char

I have a .txt file called 'exampleWheel.txt' which contains 10 characters: A,M,W,O,S,E,G,L,P,H.

[image]

I am trying to store the characters inside an array so that I can reference to each character later according to its position in the array.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("exampleWheel.txt","r");
    int i = 0;

    char singleLine[150];
    const char *array[10];

    while(!feof(fPointer)){
        fgets(singleLine, 150, fPointer);
        array[i] = singleLine;
        printf("%d\n",&array[i]);
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fPointer);

    printf("array[0] = %c\n", array[0]);
    printf("array[1] = %c\n", array[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The printf statements in the while loop return the correct output but the two printf outside the while loop returns the wrong results.

i.e **printf("array[0] = %c\n", array[0])** does not return the first character of the array

Please show me how to improve my code. 
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- when opening a file you should always check for errors and handle them e.g. inform the user and end the program with an error code
- try to read from a file and don't check upfront with feof, please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
- the assignment `array[i] = singleLine;` stores a pointer to the singleLine character array, but it will be overwritten with the next fgets call in the loop. As an alternative you could use e.g. a two-dimensional array here and simply save the first character.
- you should make sure to not read more lines then you have space for in `array`, otherwise you write over then end of the array

You slightly modified code could look like this then:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX_LINES 10

int main() {
    char singleLine[150];
    char array[MAX_LINES][2];

    FILE *fPointer;
    if ((fPointer = fopen("exampleWheel.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_LINES && fgets(singleLine, 150, fPointer)) {
        array[i][0] = singleLine[0];
        array[i][1] = '\0';
        printf("%d\n", *array[i]);
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fPointer);

    printf("array[0] = %c\n", array[0][0]);
    printf("array[1] = %c\n", array[1][0]);
    return 0;
}
```